# Using substitution method to prove or disprove a recurrence assertion

Tags: induction, asymptotics, recurrence-relations

I need to prove or disprove for $T(n)=3T(\frac{2n}{3})+5n^2+4n$ where $T(n)=1$ it holds that $T(n) \in O(n^2)$. I assumed for induction $T(\frac{2n}{3}) \leq c(\frac{4n^2}{9})- d\frac{2n}{3}$ holds true. After plugging in, I finally reach $T(n) \leq cn^2-dn+5n^2+\frac{cn^2}{3}+4n+\frac{dn}{3}$. and I couldn't find any d and positive c such that $T(n)\leq cn^2-dn$.
So I am thinking that it is not $O(n^2)$ but I am missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the recurrence

$$
T\left( n\right)  = c T\left(\frac{a}{b}n \right) + f(n)
$$

with $\{a,b,n\}\in \mathbb{N}^+$, $a,b$ relative primes, $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Considering now $n = b^m q$ with $\{q,m\}\in \mathbb{N}^+$ and $q \not|\; b$, the path from $n = b^m q$ to extinction is

$$
\{b^m q, b^{m-1}a q,\cdots, b^{m-k}a^k q,\cdots,b a^{m-1}q,a^m q\}
$$

so calling now $T(a^m q)= T_{q_0}$ we have

$$
T(b^m q) = c^m T_{q_0}+\sum_{k=1}^{k=m}c^{m-k}f(a^{m-k}b^k q)
$$

Now making $\lambda = \frac ab$ and $T_{q_0}=0$ with $a = 2, b=3, c=3$ we have

$$
T(b^m q) = 4\frac{1-(3\lambda)^m}{1-3\lambda}b^m q+5\frac{1-(3\lambda^2)^m}{1-3\lambda^2}(b^m q)^2
$$

now as $3\lambda \gt 1$ and $m\to \infty$ considering $q=1$ we have

$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}T(b^m) \approx 5(3\lambda^2)^{m-1}(b^m)^2
$$

and as $n = b^m$ finally we have asymptotically

$$
T(n)=\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac 43\right)^{\log_3 n}n^2\right)
$$

Comment: thank you really clear!